# Great Expectations custom expectation not ignoring nulls as requested

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, great-expectations

Versions of the libraries we're using:

```
snowconn==3.7.1
snowflake-connector-python==2.3.10
snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.3
SQLAlchemy==1.3.23
great_expectations==0.13.10
pandas==1.1.5
```

Note we're grabbing data from Snowflake on our own and then feeding a dataframe of it into Great Expectations. I'm aware GE has a Snowflake data source and it's on my list to add it. But I think this setup should work even without using that data source.

We have the following Great Expectations data context config:

```
    data_context_config = DataContextConfig(
        datasources={
            datasource_name: DatasourceConfig(
                class_name='PandasDatasource',
                data_asset_type={
                    'module_name': 'dataqa.dataset',
                    'class_name': 'CustomPandasDataset'
                }
            )
        },
        store_backend_defaults=S3StoreBackendDefaults(
            default_bucket_name=METADATA_BUCKET,
            expectations_store_prefix=EXPECTATIONS_PATH,
            validations_store_prefix=VALIDATIONS_PATH,
            data_docs_prefix=DATA_DOCS_PATH,
        ),
        validation_operators={
            "action_list_operator": {
                "class_name": "ActionListValidationOperator",
                "action_list": [
                    {
                        "name": "store_validation_result",
                        "action": {"class_name": "StoreValidationResultAction"},
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "store_evaluation_params",
                        "action": {"class_name": "StoreEvaluationParametersAction"},
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "update_data_docs",
                        "action": {"class_name": "UpdateDataDocsAction"},
                    },
                ],
            }
        }
    )
    ge_context = BaseDataContext(project_config=data_context_config)
```

`CustomPandasDataset` is defined as:

```
class CustomPandasDataset(PandasDataset):
    _data_asset_type = "CustomPandasDataset"

    @MetaPandasDataset.multicolumn_map_expectation
    def expect_column_A_equals_column_B_column_C_ratio(
        self,
        column_list,
        ignore_row_if='any_value_is_missing'
    ):
        column_a = column_list.iloc[:,0]
        column_b = column_list.iloc[:,1]
        column_c = column_list.iloc[:,2]

        return abs(column_a - (1.0 - (column_b/column_c))) <= 0.001
```

and called like:

```
    cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    batch.expect_column_A_equals_column_B_column_C_ratio(
        cols,
        catch_exceptions=True
    )
```

Later on we validate the data context like so:

```
    return ge_context.run_validation_operator(
        "action_list_operator",
        assets_to_validate=batches,
        run_id=run_id)["success"]
```

Often times, columns `a` and `b` are `null` in our data. Given I've set the `ignore_row_if='any_value_is_missing'` flag on the custom expectation, I'm expecting rows with `null` values in any of columns `a`, `b`, or `c` to be skipped. But Great Expectations doesn't skip them, instead adding them to the `unexpected`, or "failed" field of output:

```
result  
element_count   1000
missing_count   0
missing_percent 0
unexpected_count    849
unexpected_percent  84.89999999999999
unexpected_percent_total    84.89999999999999
unexpected_percent_nonmissing   84.89999999999999result 
element_count   1000
missing_count   0
missing_percent 0
unexpected_count    849
unexpected_percent  84.89999999999999
unexpected_percent_total    84.89999999999999
unexpected_percent_nonmissing   84.89999999999999


partial_unexpected_list 

0   
a   null
b   null
c   1.63
```

I'm unsure why this is happening. In the Great Expectations [source](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/blob/352514a9dc33543ab1b6039f463a57449f445fd2/great_expectations/dataset/pandas_dataset.py#L267), the `multicolumn_map_expectation` does:

```
...
            elif ignore_row_if == "any_value_is_missing":
                boolean_mapped_skip_values = test_df.isnull().any(axis=1)
...
            boolean_mapped_success_values = func(
                self, test_df[boolean_mapped_skip_values == False], *args, **kwargs
            )
            success_count = boolean_mapped_success_values.sum()
            nonnull_count = (~boolean_mapped_skip_values).sum()
            element_count = len(test_df)

            unexpected_list = test_df[
                (boolean_mapped_skip_values == False)
                & (boolean_mapped_success_values == False)
            ]
            unexpected_index_list = list(unexpected_list.index)

            success, percent_success = self._calc_map_expectation_success(
                success_count, nonnull_count, mostly
            )
```

which I interpret as ignoring `null`-containing rows (*not* adding them to the `unexpected` list and not using them to determine `percent_success`). I've dropped a `pdb` in our code and verified that the dataframe we're calling the expectation on can be manipulated in the correct way to get "sensible" data (`test_df.isnull().any(axis=1)`), but for some reason Great Expectations is allowing those nulls to slip through. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the poster filed a Github issue here: https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/2460. The progress can be tracked there.